# EMACS :: linum-mode and size of font (unreadable line numbers)

Tags: emacs, font-size

When using linum-mode in emacs and when increase font by `M-x text-scale-increase`, there is the one thing that bothers me. Font for line numbers have same size as reading and **don't fit** into `left-margin` on left side of buffer!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy1qd.png)
Normal font-size, OK[image: Everything works as should be]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggUsp.png)
Increased font-size, no longer readable   FUUUUU[image]

---

*`What I'd really like to have:`*

When **increase/decrease font** I want one of these to work

1. then **increase/decrease width of left-margin** (resp. left-fringe) accordingly
2. then don't change font for left-margin **but increase/decrease *spacing* between line numbers**

   *Does anybody have some suggestions?
    Thanks, guys*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at these two links:

1. [my question on the same issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7507/emacs-text-scale-adjust-causes-line-numbers-column-to-incrementally-shrink-and-d/30425#30425)
2. [my workaround for this issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30087/2343)

It works quite well enough for my needs.

Examples:

[image]
1
[image]

Comment: +1 I'm quite satisfied. Definitely good way to go, `but` there are some issues with this. For example line numbers not always decrease its size. I don't understand all of the code, it's probably solvable but don't know how yet. I don't mark this answer as 'accepted' at this time, Peter. Probably will later.  Thanks.

Comment: The method is based on scaling by a *fixed* factor of 1.04 (chosen as a *reasonable* value). This linear decrease does not always match up with the *next* available  font size, and so you need to press the key again until it scales to the next available size.  This occurs more frequently as the font size becomes smaller. I worked around it for zooming bigger, by empirically building a list of the scaling step increments needed to jump directly to tne next font. This list suits my font, but as I mentioned in one of my links, I don't know how to determint the size of the next available font.

Comment: PS: You can see in the list `sub-zoom-ht`, which is a list of font sizes for a given number of scalings (the index), that there are a lot of repeating font sizes.  The, *zoom bigger* logic uses this list, but  there is no equivalent list for *zoom smaller*.. It wasn't worth bothering about, as it is not the "right" way to do it, and was very time consuming, and it works..  One day I may stumble on how to access the font info directly...

Comment: I haven't found anything better :-). I think I get it now; and thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest, most straightforward solution I've seen is to set the line numbers to a fixed height. This can be accomplished easily, in accordance with [user78810](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/78810/user78810user78810)'s answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29786/font-size-issues-with-emacs-in-linum-mode/146781#146781

To wit, add the following line in your emacs config (or to your `dotspacemacs/user-config` function, if you're using spacemacs):

```
(eval-after-load "linum"
  '(set-face-attribute 'linum nil :height 100))
```

Comment: Works like a dream even 7 years later. 

Answer (score 5):

```
M-x customize-face [RETURN] linum-mode
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I can fix that problem with the following code:

```
(require 'linum)
(defun linum-update-window-scale-fix (win)
  "fix linum for scaled text"
  (set-window-margins win
          (ceiling (* (if (boundp 'text-scale-mode-step)
                  (expt text-scale-mode-step
                    text-scale-mode-amount) 1)
              (if (car (window-margins))
                  (car (window-margins)) 1)
              ))))
(advice-add #'linum-update-window :after #'linum-update-window-scale-fix)
```

It seems to work, at least with 24.5.

Comment: On Emacs 26.1 this keeps increasing the width of line numbers column, eventually making the window unusable.

Answer (score 3):

I would comment on the solution based on `customize-face` if I could.  It works well for me.  The actual face is `linum` rather than `linum-mode`, at least in my `emacs-24.3.1`.  In the customization buffer, I clicked on "Show all attributes" and then set the face height to 100 tenths of a point.  If a fixed-size face for the line numbers is acceptable to you (as it is to me) the solution based on `customize-face` is straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable `linum-mode` and use `display-line-numbers-mode` instead which is part of Emacs since version 26 and scales well when increasing font size.

E.g. your config can look like:

```lisp
;; (global-linum-mode 1)
(global-display-line-numbers-mode)
```